# Give me my KILL-power when something goes wrong

Tags: mysql, linux, kill, top, command-line-interface

We've had it a few times now. Suddenly our production server won't respond because a process is in an infinite loop, or the MySQL server stops serving new requests because one query is blocking everything...

We SSH to the server and use `ps aux` or `top` to find the culprit, or `mytop` or `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in MySQL to find the offending process ID and `kill` it. Then offcourse we try to recreate the situation on the testserver and fix the bug.

But sometimes the server is so well hung your `ps aux` / `top` / `mytop` / `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` won't go through - even the admins are blocked.

**What is the best way to ensure an admin can always access the server and kill offending processes or queries (both on Linux and MySQL)?**

- Can we allocate priorities to different users?
- Reserve a part of the resources for root?

I've checked [nice(1)](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/nice.1.php), but constantly having an open connection with nice -20 seems a bit excessive and difficult to work with (let alone dangerous as root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pam_limits.so module it's a nifty tool to limit memory, open files, ... and to set **nice priority** for users and groups.

```
rpm -ql pam | grep limits
man limits.conf
less /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Answer (score 7):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: Interesting, but getting physical access is not always possible (and getting into the serverroom is quite a process...) - does anyone have any experience with the remote sysrqd mentioned on the wiki page?

Comment: You can install a KVM over IP and then use Magic SysRq Keys.

Answer (score 3):

We use Dell servers that have a remote access network card (DRAC) installed that allows us to access the server out of band via ssh or a web browser. We can get to a console screen, or power cycle the server. Most major server vendors support some similar device.

This doesn't help you if you want to log into a server that has 0 resources available to allow a login. Short of reserving resources for a log in, this is the next best thing to physical access to the server.

It sounds like you have issues surrounding problem applications. Why do you have apps that are going into infinite loops and MySQL queries that are exhausting your server resources?

Answer (score 2):

I guess my answer wasn't good enough and someone felt the need to delete it.

monit or god, preempt things taking over by setting limits.  If you're running virtual iron rather than bare metal, assign all but one core to your process and save one core for console access.  KVM over IP can sometimes allow you to enter a key combination on the console. If network activity is doing it, shut off eth0 until things calm down, connect on eth1.

Comment: I answered the question earlier in a bit more detail, I didn't delete the answer.  I came back to see someone else's potential solutions and noticed my original answer was gone.  While you may say that answers aren't deleted, I have had several answers deleted where a higher karma user disagrees with my answer and has gotten upvoted on his incorrect answer, so, thanks for playing.

Comment: There are less than 10 users on the system who could have deleted your answer, only three of which I know of who actively moderate, and I can't imagine any of them deleting your answer without cause. But really, you should go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com - If your answers are getting deleted, there's a reason (and it may be a bug in the code, not malicious intent). It's important to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/slurm.html) could be the answer.
It's a QoS Resource Manager for linux based cluster systems.